# How to display text below all div

Tags: html, css

I want to display some message below all div. But it is display inside div.

I upload my css and html code and snap of the output.

[image]

```css
.round .shape{
    background-size: 560px;
    background-position: 0px 2px;
    width: 66px;
    height: 69px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img.shape {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .img
  {
    margin-right: 52px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .shape
{
  background-image: url('../images/diamondshape.jpg'); 

}
```

```html
<label for="ABC" class="round">
              <div class="img shape" ></div>
<span>A</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Why don't you put the text after the div instead of putting it inside?

Comment: If i put outside div then it will display right side of div

Comment: Can you make a sketch of what you actually want in paint?

Comment: see the image...i point out...it is display besides div.. i want to display below div

Comment: Use `<img>` to display the image?

Comment: no... in shape class background image set in div tag

Comment: Just use Div Tag instead Span Tag...! Try my code, May be this will help u...!

Comment: A div is not allowed to be inside a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay to change the data span to div?? If you change that span to div then it works fine...Try this

```css
.round .shape{
    background-size: 560px;
    background-position: 0px 2px;
    width: 66px;
    height: 69px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img.shape {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .img
  {
    margin-right: 52px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .shape
{
  background-image: url('../images/diamondshape.jpg'); 

}
```

```html
<label for="ABC" class="round">
              <div class="img shape" ></div>
<div>A</div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `span tag` and try that using pseudo selector `:before` or `:after`,

```css
   .round .shape{
    background-size: 560px;
    background-position: 0px 2px;
    width: 66px;
    height: 69px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.img.shape {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .img
  {
    margin-right: 52px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
.shape
{
  background-image: url('../images/diamondshape.jpg'); 
}
.shape:before{
  content:"A";
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:-20px;
}
.round:nth-of-type(2) > .shape:before{
  content:"B";
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:-20px;
}
```

```html
<label for="ABC" class="round">
     <div class="img shape"></div>
</label>
<label for="ABC" class="round">
     <div class="img shape"></div>
</label>
```

And if you need to keep `span tag` then set `position` of span tag to `absolute` and add `bottom 0`, thus this align text to bottom as in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onuxrtuz/).

Comment: can i set content using html instead of css?(content:"A";)

Comment: Yes @RHapani check that jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this doing this.

Your Div

```
<div class="myDiv">Hello I am a div element.</div>
```

In your css, do this

```
div.myDiv::after {
    content: " - Remember this";
}
```

This will add -Remember this text after every div having class "myDiv".

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the message inside your `<div>`. If you want the message written inside `<span>` tag to display below the `<div class="....."></div>`,the put `<span>` outside `<div class = "image..."><div>`

```
<label for="ABC" class="round">
          <div class="img shape"> <img src= "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Downloads\IMG_20161008_175150_HDR_1475929397796.jpg"></img></div>
          <span>A</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give display block to the span (.caption):

```css
.round .shape{
    background-size: 560px;
    background-position: 0px 2px;
    width: 66px;
    height: 69px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img.shape {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  .img
  {
    margin-right: 52px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .shape
{
  background-image: url('../images/diamondshape.jpg'); 

}
.caption {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<label for="ABC" class="round">
              <div class="img shape" ></div>
<span class="caption">A</span>
</label>
```